# Python Make serial output accessible to other scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-rpc, pyserial

I currently have a script that gets a feed from a serial device.

feed.py

```
from serial import Serial
ser = Serial('COM27', 9600, timeout=5)

def scrape():
    while True:
        raw = ser.readline()
        raw = raw.decode('utf-8')
        if raw == "":
            pass
        else:
            print(raw)
    #print (raw.decode('utf-8'))
scrape()
```

What I would like to do now is access that feed from other python scripts.
I did try using SimpleXMLRPCServer but could not get the output

feed.py

```
from serial import Serial
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
ser = Serial('COM27', 9600, timeout=5)

def scrape():
    while True:
        raw = ser.readline()
        raw = raw.decode('utf-8')
        if raw == "":
            pass
        else:
            print(raw)
try:
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000), allow_none=True)
    server.register_function(scrape)
    server.serve_forever()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

listener.py

```
import xmlrpc.client

feed = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8000')

print(feed.scrape())
```

I got no output from the listener scrpit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is registered then it is expected that the function returns an information, not just print it, so that is the reason for the failure of your logic.

In this case it is better to register the Serial object:

**feed.py**

```
from serial import Serial
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

ser = Serial("COM27", 9600, timeout=5)

try:
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000), allow_none=True)
    server.register_instance(ser)
    server.serve_forever()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**listener.py**

```
import xmlrpc.client

ser = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000")

while True:
    raw = ser.readline()
    if raw:
        print(raw)
```

Comment: Perfect.. What you show makes sense.  Always something simple

Answer (score 0):

`scrape` doesn't return anything but rather merely prints output, that's your immediate problem, but as you're looking to stream data, you'd have to fill a buffer and read from it continuously, making XML-RPC (or any other RPC based protocol) unsuitable.

XML-RPC carries a lot of overhead as it operates on several layers above TCP, which is all you need for data streaming purposes. This means on every `scrape` call, you'll also be generating and sending HTTP and XML payload.

If you're familiar with asynchronous programming, start with [asyncio](https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html). If not, I'd start with [sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html); if you're planning on having more than a single consumer, look into [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html).